# Is it possible to build a multigraph with Memgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

Is it possible to build a multigraph (interconnected multilayer network) with Memgraph?? Or will it be possible in near future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are speaking of a multigraph as a graph that is permitted to have multiple relationships, that is relationships that have the same end nodes, that is possible in Memgraph.
You can create the same nodes and relationships as many times as you want, and that's why you have to be careful when to `create` and when to `merge` a node/relationship you are importing to your database.
There are two ways of having multiple relationships between the same start and end nodes. First, you can create relationships of **different type** and second, you can create relationships of the **same type**.
For example, let's say you have two nodes labeled as ***Person*** (Anna and James) and two types of relationships between them (**LOVES, IS_MARRIED_TO**). Then you can create that with:

```
CREATE (:Person {name: "Anna"})-[:LOVES]->(:Person {name: "James"}); MATCH (n:Person {name: "Anna"}), (m:Person {name: "James"}) CREATE (n)-[:IS_MARRIED_TO]->(m);
```

Now let's say you want to create another relationship from Anna to James of type **LOVES**. You can do that with:

```
MATCH (n:Person {name: "Anna"}), (m:Person {name: "James"}) CREATE (n)-[:LOVES]->(m);
```

Since I used `CREATE` and not `MERGE`, another relationship of type **LOVES** will be created. To verify that:

```
MATCH ()-[r:LOVES]->() RETURN count(r);
```

and you get 2, since there are 2 relationships of type **LOVES**.